# How to copy files from a server to other IP

Tags: networking, copy, ip, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to copy some files from from a server to other computers that I only know the IP address. I know the source file and the destination file. I am using Windows 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options like

1. Go with Microsoft synctoy
2. FTP
3. Develop a client/server application responsible for reading/writing files.
4. winscp